# Was my Ubuntu computer hacked?

Tags: security

My Ubuntu computer's name changed to "localhost". It is a fresh install.

I only installed `myspell-pt-br`, and I've already activated my firewall.

The Ubuntu version is the 16.04.1 LTS desktop version.

Do you think I was hacked?

Comment: `localhost` is normal name used when computer reffers to itself, this is really nothing to worry about. Where do you see it ?

Comment: thanks for your help.I see on the  option "about computer"near the clock

Answer (score 6):

In computers and networking, it isn't rare to see that your host name is "localhost". On nearly every platform localhost is the name of your computer in terms of local area networking. I would recommend reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) here, if you want to learn a bit more about "Localhost".

It is also good to note that while possible, it's hard to download something malicious that can do what you are describing from the Linux application repository. There's nothing to be worried about, unless your actual username was indeed something else, and it changed to "Localhost". I've never seen or heard of such cases, so you might be in a bit too deep if that was actually the case.

I believe doing a simple

```
hostname
```

in your terminal would help you determine if it was actually changed or not.

Comment: thank you my friend. I did hostname in my terminal e saw that nothing changed. thanks very much.

Comment: @D.webMan I'm just curios. Where did your computer's name get changed then?